# Android database bug when deleting items then trying to add more

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a listview that displays a list of items that are stored in a database. I can display and edit these items perfectly fine.
The items can also be deleted fine, but the problem comes when i try to readd items after things have been deleted. Sometimes the error doesn't occur depending on how you delete things and I can't work out what is going on.

an example of the error:

I will have 3 items: a, b, c

If i delete just one of those items from any position in the list then readd it is fine, in any combination. However, if i was to delete b and c then tried to readd b, i would have a list of a, b, b. with a duplicate of b showing that crashes if selected. the first b being deleted will also delete it.

if i delete a, b and c and try and read a then i will get a list of a, a with another duplicate showing. If i was then to add b to the list i would get a, b, a, b with the same problems as before. if i keep deleting things from this point eventually when i try and readd an item i will get more and more duplicates appearing in the listview.

It's as if as many items as i delete from the list, it will then add that many duplicate items onto the end of the list to fill it up. Unless i only delete one item at a time.

I'm not sure what code to put in here. This isn't a problem with just displaying things wrong. The database is returning a list wth these duplicates in. Curious if someone might have a general idea what is going on. I'm not sure what code to post. My code is based on the tutorial found here - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

```
public long createToDo(Todo todo, long[] tag_ids) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TODO, todo.getNote());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, todo.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, todo.getPrice());
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
    values.put(KEY_PURCHASED, todo.getPurchased());
    // insert row
    long todo_id = db.insert(TABLE_TODO, null, values);

    // insert tag_ids
    for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
        createTodoTag(todo_id, tag_id);
    }

    return todo_id;
}
```

to delete the returned todo_id is sent into this delete method

```
public void deleteToDo(long tado_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TODO, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
}
```

here is the function i use to fetch the todos for each list

```
public List<Todo> getAllToDosByTag(String tag_name) {
    List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " td, "
            + TABLE_TAG + " tg, " + TABLE_TODO_TAG + " tt WHERE tg."
            + KEY_TAG_NAME + " = '" + tag_name + "'" + " AND tg." + KEY_ID
            + " = " + "tt." + KEY_TAG_ID + " AND td." + KEY_ID + " = "
            + "tt." + KEY_TODO_ID;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Todo td = new Todo();
            td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
            td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
            td.setStatus(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS))));
            td.setPrice(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE))));
            td.setPurchased(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PURCHASED))));
            // adding to todo list
            todos.add(td);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return todos;
}
```

and here's how i am displaying them in my other activity

```
              listOfTodos = db.getAllToDosByTag(nameOfList);

          final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItems);
              lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, listOfTodos);
```

-

```
public long createTodoTag(long todo_id, long tag_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TODO_ID, todo_id);
    values.put(KEY_TAG_ID, tag_id);
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    long id = db.insert(TABLE_TODO_TAG, null, values);

    return id;
}
```

Comment: What is createTodoTag method? Are there multiple tables here that are associated together?

Comment: there are three tables: one with the todos, one with the tags and another that binds the two of them together. so if you were to delete a tag then all the todos associated with it would be deleted

Comment: here is the code from it    public long createTodoTag(long todo_id, long tag_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TODO_ID, todo_id);
        values.put(KEY_TAG_ID, tag_id);
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
 
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_TODO_TAG, null, values);
 
        return id;
    }

Comment: Are you deleting all the values in the other tables when you delete the main entry? Have you verified that? Have you verified that the data being returned by the database is wrong and its not your adapter/list that is displaying it wrong?

Comment: in your `deleteToDo`, you don't cascade the deletion to `TABLE_TODO_TAG`, do you?

Comment: Ok yeah, I think i fixed it. I was deleting the todo from the todo table, but not deleting it from the todo_tag table as you guys suggested. I actually thought that wasn't relevenat here for the particular todo part, since the tutorial never did that either, but turns out it was. Cheers for the help!